# Pip install: can't open file pip, or Parent module '' not loaded

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, installation, pip

Thanks for reading this in the first place.

I'm trying to install Django. So here's what I do in the command line:

```
C:\>python34 pip install Django
```

And here's what I get:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I do the same from the site-packages directory:

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages>python34 pip install Django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "pip\__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .runner import run
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I used pip before, and it worked fine, but now I don't know how to run it properly... I tried to find an answer first, but I don't understand any of them. Probably because I'm relatively new to all this. Could anyone explain in first-grade-level-language what I need to do to get this right?

Answer (score 26):

Assuming you have pip installed and you want to do this through python as opposed to the standalone pip client, you can also do

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, even if its a simple response.

Comment: Why does this work? What does -m do? Google won't turn up anything

Answer (score 6):

The command `pip` is not a Python module. It is an executable. This should work:

```
C:\> pip install Django
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The answer below also works probably, but this is cleaner. One addition: I had to add C:\Python34\Scripts to the windows path. Don't know how it worked earlier though... Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, pip on Windows installs to C:\Python34\Scripts by default. So, if that's isn't on your system path, you'd actually need to do this:

```
C:\> \Python34\Scripts\pip install Django
```

Also, read up in virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. It'll make your life a lot easier - cheers.