# can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I am trying to install Jinja2 package with following command line

```
python pip install Jinja2
```

and I get the error

```
can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I checked and pip is both in my python Lib and Script so I don't understand.

Also tried

```
python pip -m install Jinja2
```

It is not the first time I get the error but I can't remember how I worked it out last time.

Comment: Don't call `python` - just `pip install Jinja2`

Comment: @Tim I see, wasn't sure which I had to use. Also tried this one but then I get "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "c:\users\vincent\desktop\progra\python36-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe" "

Comment: It should be python -m pip install Jinja2

Comment: @miles82 Got it thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864307/pip-install-cant-open-file-pip-or-parent-module-not-loaded#31971858). Which is also what [miles82](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842511/cant-open-file-pip-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory#comment94533274_53842511) said in this question.

```sh
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

But it doesn't have an explanation. So, to complete that answer, if you type:

```sh
python -h
```

It returns a help text, and we can see that **-m** means:

```sh
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

And that's why you type **pip** as a library module after **-m**, so you can download your desire package.

(I'm new to python, so if I got some wrong, feel free to correct me).